# Qualified name is not allowed in C++

Tags: c++

I am beginner in C++ and have to  work on a project. The following code is provided(header file) and when i import it , i get the error for namespace Utils.

```
 namespace Utils::iterators {

  struct RetrieveKey {
    template<typename T>
      typename T::first_type operator()(T keyValuePair) const {
        return keyValuePair.first;
      }
  };
```

The error is .

```
 "qualified name is not allowed".
```

I imported only boost library.

I have been busy with these errors for hours,if someone can tell me what the possible reason is of this error, it would be a great help.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly but I think the issue is the: `T::` in front of the `first_type`.

Comment: Make sure you are compiling with C++17 since your header uses nested namespace specifiers like `namespace Utils::iterators { ... }`.  Add the `-std=c++17` flag for GCC/clang, or `/std:c++latest` with MSVC.

Comment: @Rietty The error occurs at the declaration of `Utils :: iterators`.

Comment: @0x5453 Indeed that was the problem and it is solved. Thank you very much. If you want , write it as answer and i will accept and may be it will be helpful for someone else who is beginner in C++.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make sure you are compiling with C++17 since your header uses nested namespace specifiers (e.g. `namespace Utils::iterators { ... }`).

This can be done with the `-std=c++17` flag for GCC/clang, or `/std:c++latest` for MSVC.

Comment: really a sneaky problem